# GGplot Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric >

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to Rstudio. I am supposed to plot a histogram of a new variable.  The variable is likely to be a factor variable. I used `as.numeric` to recode. My code is below:

```
anes$libcpo_final<-revalue(anes$libcpo_self, c("-9. Refused" =-9, "-8. Don't know"=-9, "-7. Deleted due to partial (post-election) interview" =-9, "-6. Not asked, unit nonresponse (no post-election interview)"=-9, "-2. Haven't thought much {do not probe}"=-9, "1. Extremely liberal" =-3, "2. Liberal"=-2,"3. Slightly liberal"=-1,"4. Moderate; middle of the road"=0,"5. Slightly conservative"=1,"6. Conservative"=2,"7. Extremely conservative"=3))
```

library(ggplot2)

## Exercise 1 B:

```
libcpo_new<-as.numeric(anes$libcpo_final)
hist(libcpo_new)
ggplot(libcpo_new, aes(x=libcpo_new))
```

Here is the error:

```
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric
```

Comment: Hi Dione, and welcome to StackOverflow! If you want to have your question answered, you should make it more readable for other users: use code blocks, layout the code (don't leave it all on one line!), take care of how you write. Otherwise the question becomes difficult to read or even understand!

Comment: @Sean it is good to see a friendly comment advising a new user on how to present their question. Some users can be so cruel!! +1